# Service IP is not accessible across nodes in kubernetes

Tags: azure, proxy, cluster-computing, kubernetes

I have created a kubernetes v1.2 running in Azure cloud with one master(**Master**) and two nodes(**Node1** and **Node2**). I have deployed an **Nginx** and **Tomcat** application. Both the containers are deployed in individual **pods** with **RC** and they have a **SERVICE** for each.

**Nginx pod** is deployed in the **Node1** and **Tomcat pod** is deployed in **Node2**. Now **Nginx** from **Node1** is trying to access **Tomcat** via **tomcat's ServiceIP(clusterIP)** which is in **Node2**. But its unreachable.

> Nginx serviceIP: 10.16.0.2   Node1
>
> Tomcat serviceIP: 10.16.0.4 Node2

I tried ***curl 10.16.0.4:8080*** from **Node2**, it works. But same from **Node1** fails with ***curl: (52) Empty reply from server***

So communication to serviceIP across nodes fails. Is this the problem with kube v1.2?

Note: ClusterIP for the Service will be specified at the time of creating the service.

Comment: Can you reach the Tomcat pod's IP directly? That will help determine whether it is a service routing problem or a more general networking issue.

Comment: Which overlay network plugin are you using ? . Are you using iptables mode or userspace mode ? Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088224/what-does-userspace-mode-means-in-kube-proxys-proxy-mode

Comment: @CJCullen I can reach the pods via its IP from the same node and not from the different node. Curl 10.32.0.2:8080 from Node2 reaches Tomcat, same from Node1 fails

Comment: do you have DNS setup?

Comment: @MrE I don't have DNS setup(no addons installes). Do we need DNS setup for inter-node communication?

Comment: Pods usually communicate through Services, and Services use DNS, so in practice you do need DNS especially to keep track of the IPs that may change. Now I actually think the problems is that a Pod cannot call its own IP, which really seem to be what you're doing. Pods talk through their localhost address. I believe the reason is that it that would cause endless loops if you could (i.e. a Pod is not supposed to call itself)

Comment: I can reach a pod(via its ip) from the same node in which it is running. But can't from a different node. Does DNS has a role in this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to reach the cluster ip from the Node2, it looks like the service selector is properly defined.

Kube-proxy is the component that watches the services and creates iptable rules for end points. I would check if kube-proxy is running properly on Node1. Then check if iptable rules are set properly for the cluster ip you are trying to reach. 
You can see these with `iptables -L -t nat | grep namespace/servicename`

Here is an example:

`bash-4.3# iptables -L -t nat | grep kube-system/heapster
KUBE-MARK-MASQ  all  --  172.168.16.182       anywhere             /* kube-system/heapster: */
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kube-system/heapster: */ tcp to:172.168.16.182:8082
KUBE-SVC-BJM46V3U5RZHCFRZ  tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.172.66       /* kube-system/heapster: cluster IP */ tcp dpt:http
KUBE-SEP-KNJP5BBKUOCH7NDB  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kube-system/heapster: */`

In this example I looked up heapster running in kube-system namespace. It is showing that the cluster ip is `192.168.172.66` DNATs to the endpoint 172.168.16.182, which is pods ip (You should cross check this with the endpoints listed in `kubectl describe service`.

If is it not there, restarting kube-proxy might help.