# How to set kubernetes proxy for a websocket application which running from ALB of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, proxy, kubernetes, elastic-load-balancer

Using AWS to run kubernetes cluster which installed by `kops`.

Using `alb-ingress-controller` to realize application load balancer(ALB) on AWS.

Deployed a `websocket` application into the kubernetes cluster. When try to access the application from ALB DNS, because of it's using load balancer, so sometimes can't catch the response. It's went to the target group one by one.

Maybe the default `proxy-mode` of `kube-proxy` is `iptables`, so thinking about change `iptable` to `userspace`, here is a related question:

> [What does userspace mode means in kube-proxy's proxy mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088224/what-does-userspace-mode-means-in-kube-proxys-proxy-mode)

But is it the right way? To make sure the websocket application can run correctly on AWS using ALB?

If it's the right way, then how to change `kube-proxy`'s `proxy-mode` to `userspace`?

Here is another article about running socket.io application on kubernetes:

> [Running Socket.IO Applications on Kubernetes](https://deis.com/blog/2016/socket.io-applications-kubernetes/)

But it's using ELB. And the method seems a little complex.

Finding a good way.